# Dynamically filling table with json data taking too long

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I have following table which is dynamically changed when some event happens:

```
<div class="scrollable" id="time-stats">
    <table id='table126'>
       <thead>
        <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
          <td  id="time-stats-name">Time stats</td>
          <td  id = "time-stats-date"></td>
          <td  id = "operator_name"></td>
          <td  id = "window_number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th id="operator_title"></th>
          <th id="windowsNo"></th>
          <th id="laneName"></th>
          <th class="ticket_number"></th>
          <th class="create_time"></th>
          <th id="startTime"></th>
          <th id="endTime"></th>
          <th class="waiting_time"></th>
          <th id="duration"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

It is dynamically filled with json data(_durationStats in this case) in javascript like so:

```
html = "";
var time_stats_tbody = jQuery("#time-stats tbody");

jQuery(_durationStats).each(function(ix) {
    var el = _durationStats[ix];
    html +="<tr";
    if(operator_ == "allOperators"){
        html+=" data-lane='" + el.target+ "'><td>" + _units[el.target]+ 
        "</td><td>" + el.windowNo+ "</td>";
    }
    html+="><td>" +
    el.laneText+"</td><td>"
    + el.ticketNo + "</td><td>"
    + el.createTime + "</td><td>"
    + el.startTime + "</td><td>" + el.endTime
    + "</td><td>"
    + el.waitTime + "</td><td>"
    + el.duration + "</td></tr>";
});

time_stats_tbody.html(html);
```

Now, if there are too many json objects, browser freezes and it takes long time to build the table. Namely, I suspect the last javascript line time_stats_tbody.html(html); is taking too long. What can I do to optimize it?

Comment: How many records are you dealing with? Are you grabbing all the data at once or are you grabbing say 10 at a time to display just 10 rows to the user?

Comment: Best to do this asynchronously so the browser doesn't freeze and with a waiting spinner so the user knows that something is happening. You can then also use pagination (so only get 10 or 20 records at a time).

Comment: manipulate dom with such tools as angular i think will increase speed :)

Comment: Thousands. It varies each time depending how much does user want to see. I'm grabbing all at once, as I don't know how to show only several records at a time. Could anybody show me an example?

Comment: @GomatoX which one is better in my situation: moving to angularjs or asynchronously paginating?

Comment: I think better one is to chunk your data and have pagination, lots of data can cause older computers to break, especially older browser. But you can show not all data, i had similar problem i solved it by showing points and then it's visible loading it, here it is http://www.ldkistorija.lt/index.php/laiko-juosta/11717

Comment: I'm thinking of using something like this http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html  But I'm not sure if it asynchronous? And if it is applicable for dynamically changed tables?

Comment: @Nazerke - Moving to angular because something doesn't work would be like saying you should turn gay because you had one bad date with a girl. Easiest option I would suggest is you do this in increments. First, load 10 records. Wait a second then load the next 10 records. Keep doing this until you've loaded all the records. Additional thing I would recommend is you cache the JSON objects in local or session storage so next time you view the page you won't have to load the rows in again so you can continue from where you left off.

Comment: @ninty9notout I have several such tables. I once worked in angularjs and remember how it was like a piece of cake to do similar things. Never hurts considering!
Is there readily available libraries for what you are describing? I'm thinking of using something like this tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html But I'm not sure if it asynchronous? And if it is applicable for dynamically changed tables?